# How to change ErrorMessage MVC DropDownListFor

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I have a class with simple properties in it.

```
public class Projects
    {

        private static readonly WebWideMediaDataContext _ctx = new WebWideMediaDataContext();


        public string Title { get; set; }


        public string Description { get; set; }


        private readonly List<ProjectCategoryModel> _categories = _ctx.ProjectCategories.GetAll();


        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a project type.")]
        public int SelectedProjectCategoryId { get; set; }

        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryList
        {
            get
            {
                var categoryList = _categories.Select(s => new SelectListItem
                                                                {
                                                                    Value = s.CategoryId.ToString(),
                                                                    Text = s.CategoryName
                                                                });

                return DefaultListItem.Concat(categoryList);
            }
        }



        public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> DefaultListItem
        {
            get
            {
                return Enumerable.Repeat(new SelectListItem
                {
                    Value = "select",
                    Text = "Select an Option"
                }, count: 1);
            }
        }


    }
```

And in my view I have a DropDownListFor

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.SelectedProjectCategoryId, Model.CategoryList)
```

After I hit submit button, I got the validation error message but not the one which I have manuaully defined in the model. I got this error message "The field SelectedProjectCategoryId must be a number."   instead the one which I have defined "Please select a project type"

Can someone please suggest what should I need to fix?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your validation is failing for Integer data type and not for Required field .

Try as follows:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a project type.")]
[RegularExpression("\\d+", ErrorMessage = "Please select a project type")]
public int SelectedProjectCategoryId { get; set; }
```